# Kind=dp integer size in Fortran90

Tags: c, fortran

I'm currently trying to get two programs to communicate with each other, one of which is written in C, the other in Fortran 90. As part of this, I need to pass a pointer to an integer containing the size of a real number in the fortran program to the program in C. 
All the real number variables in the Fortran program have

```
real (kind=dp)
```

As their type, so my question is what is the size of this kind of variable?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/STORAGE_005fSIZE.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/C_005fSIZEOF.html#C_005fSIZEOF

Comment: If you combine C and Fortran, you should really be using Fortran 2003 and not 90, which is obsolete.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot rewrite the Fortran 90 program in 2003. However this has put me on the right track, thank you

Comment: There is no rewriting necessary. It is about using the right features.

Comment: You're almost certainly already using the latest Fortran (2003 and parts of 2008) already.